# Using TestSuites in JUnit5

Tags: junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

I like testing similar types of classes with the same code, so I don't forget to do stuff. Using JUnit4 (technically Junit3) I created classes like this:

```java
@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public class MyPojoTest {

    public static TestSuite suite() {
        return PojoTestSuite.forPojoClass(MyPojo.class)
            // test Serializable is implemented correctly
            .serializable()
            // test Comparable is implemented correctly
            .comparable()
            // etc.
            .cloneable()
            // creates a junit.framework.TestSuite
            .create();
    }
}

public class PojoTestSuite {

    public static PojoTestSuite forPojoClass(Class<?> pojoClass) {
        return new PojoTestSuite(pojoClass);
    }

    public TestSuite create() {
        final TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

        suite.addTest(new EqualsTest());
        suite.addTest(new HashCodeTest());

        if (this.serializable) {
            suite.addTest(new SerializeableTest());
        }
        if (this.cloneable) {
            suite.addTest(new CloneableTest());
        }
        if (this.comparable) {
            suite.addTest(new ComparableTest());
        }
        return suite;
    }

    // getters and setters, constructor, ...
}
```

However I wasn't able to implement something like it in pure JUnit4 and now in JUnit5 I can't find anything like it either.

Is there any way to use test suites to create a set of tests dynamically? I'd like to have the tests as small as possible, because having "`testEqualsReturnsTrueForSameObject()`" fail is a lot more useful than having "`testPojo()`" fail.